# Split array into different size chunks (4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, etc)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have an array like so: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]`. I need to chunk it into different size chunks, yet with a simple pattern of: 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3 like so:

```
[
    [ // four
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ],
    [ // three (1/3)
        5,
        6,
        7
    ],
    [ // three (2/3)
        8,
        9,
        10
    ],
    [ // three (3/3)
        11,
        12,
        13
    ],
    [ // four
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17
    ],
    [ // three (1/3)
        18,
        19,
        20
    ], // and so on..
]
```

I have tried with this code I have customized:

```
const arr; // my array of values
const chuncked = arr.reduce((acc, product, i) => {
    if (i % 3) {
        return acc;
    } else if (!didFourWayReduce) {
        didFourWayReduce = true;
        fourWayReduces++;

        if ((fourWayReduces - 1) % 2) { // only make every second a "4 row"
            return [...acc, arr.slice(i, i + 3)];
        } else {
            return [...acc, arr.slice(i, i + 4)];
        }
    } else {
        didFourWayReduce = false;
        return [...acc, arr.slice(i, i + 3)];
    }
}, []);
```

And it works, almost, expect that the first chunk of threes (1/3) have the last element of the chunk with 4. So 1 key is repeated every first chunk of three. Like so:

```
[
    [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ],
    [
        4, // this one is repeated, and it shouldn't be
        5,
        6
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could take two indices, one for the data array and one for sizes. Then slice the array with a given length and push the chunk to the chunks array.

Proceed until end of data.

```js
var data = Array.from({ length: 26 }, (_, i) => i + 1),
    sizes = [4, 3, 3, 3],
    i = 0,
    j = 0,
    chunks = [];

while (i < data.length) chunks.push(data.slice(i, i += sizes[j++ % sizes.length]));

console.log(chunks);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That's beautiful. Can it be adjusted so it's for an infinite long array? I see you define length and sizes fixed.

Comment: if works already for the pattern of `sizes` with `j` and a remainder for the length of `sizes`.

Comment: Love your skills Nina. Incredible how short you made that!!

Answer (score 3):

A recursive approach is fairly elegant:

```js
const chunks = (xs, [s, ...ss]) =>
  xs.length ? [xs .slice (0, s), ... chunks (xs .slice (s), [...ss, s])] : []

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
const sizes = [4, 3, 3, 3]

console .log (chunks (data, sizes))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

By replacing `[s, ...ss]` with `[...ss, s]`, we pass a cycled version of the sizes array, so that for instance, `[4, 3, 3, 3]` becomes `[3, 3, 3, 4]`.  This makes it easy to parse step-by-step.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Yes, no one said this was performant, only elegant.  We could certainly write a similar version that works only on the indices, but it would probably be less enticing.

Comment: For instance, `const chunks = (xs, ss, i = 0, j = 0) =>
  i < xs.length ? [xs .slice (i, i + ss[j]), ... chunks (xs, ss, i + ss[j], (j + 1) % ss.length)] : []`

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, i) => i);

const copy = [...arr];

const sizes = [4, 3, 3, 3];

const result = [];

let i = 0;

while (i <= arr.length && copy.length) {
  result.push(copy.splice(0, sizes[i % sizes.length]));
  i++;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mod operator to check if it should be 4 or 3. Use two arrays just to make it easier (can be done with one)

```js
const groupIt = arr => arr.reduce(({
  group,
  out
}, v, i) => {
  var max = out.length % 4 === 0 ? 4 : 3
  group.push(v)
  if (group.length === max || i === arr.length - 1) {
    out.push(group)
    group = []
  }
  return {
    group,
    out
  }
}, {
  group: [],
  out: []
}).out

console.log(groupIt([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]))

var test = (new Array(30)).fill(0).map((x,i) => i + 1)
console.log(groupIt(test))
```

with just one:

```js
const groupIt = arr => arr.reduce((out, v, i) => {
  var max = (out.length - 1) % 4 === 0 ? 4 : 3
  out[out.length - 1].push(v)
  if (out[out.length - 1].length === max) {
    out.push([])
  }
  return out
}, [[]])

console.log(groupIt([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]))

var test = (new Array(30)).fill(0).map((x, i) => i + 1)
console.log(groupIt(test))
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is similar to that of [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60231868/3982562), but uses a *for* loop, which I personally find more clear.

```js
const arr = Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i) => i + 1);
const sizes = [4, 3, 3, 3];
const result = [];

for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i += sizes[j], j = (j + 1) % sizes.length) {
  result.push(arr.slice(i, i + sizes[j]));
}

console.log(result);
```